# Timeout of basicPublish when server is outofspace

Tags: rabbitmq

My case is rabbitmq server got out of space, just as below

```
Filesystem                       1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ramonubuntu--vg-root   6299376 5956336         0 100% /
```

The producer publishes message to server(the message needs to be persisted), and then will be blocked forever, it will keeping waiting the response of publishing. Sure we should avoid the situation of server out of space, but is there any timeout mechanism to let producer quit the waiting?

I have tried heartbeat and SO_TIMEOUT, they both don't work, as the network works fine. Below is my producer.

```
 protected void publish(byte[] message) throws Exception {
    // ConnectionFactory can be reused between threads.
    ConnectionFactory factory = new SoTimeoutConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(this.getHost());
    factory.setVirtualHost("te");
    factory.setPort(5672);
    factory.setUsername("amqp");
    factory.setPassword("amqp");
    factory.setConnectionTimeout(10 * 1000);
    // doesn't help if server got out of space
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(1);
    final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    // declare a 'topic' type of exchange
    channel.exchangeDeclare(this.exchangeName, "topic", true);

    channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {

        @Override
        public void handleReturn(int replyCode, String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey,
                AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            logger.warn("[X]Returned message(replyCode:" + replyCode + ",replyText:" + replyText
                    + ",exchange:" + exchange + ",routingKey:" + routingKey + ",body:" + new String(body));
        }

    });

    channel.confirmSelect();
    channel.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {

        @Override
        public void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
            logger.info("Ack: " + deliveryTag);
            // RabbitMessagePublishMain.this.release(connection);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
            logger.info("Nack: " + deliveryTag);
            // RabbitMessagePublishMain.this.release(connection);
        }

    });

    channel.basicPublish(this.exchangeName, RabbitMessageConsumerMain.EXCHANGE_NAME + ".-1", true,
            MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, message);
    channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10*1000);
    // now we can close connection
    connection.close();
}
```

It will block at 'channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10*1000);', and the SotimeoutConnectionFactory,

```
public class SoTimeoutConnectionFactory extends ConnectionFactory {

    @Override
    protected void configureSocket(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        super.configureSocket(socket);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Also I captured the network between producer and rabbimq,
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement [Connection Block/Unblocked](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html).

This is basically a way of notifying the publisher that the server is running out of resources. The advantage with this is that the publisher will also be notified once it is safe to publish again.

I would recommend that you take a look at this [article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html). A simple way of implementing this is to have a flag that indicates if it is safe to publish, if it is not wait until it is.

As an example you can take a look on how I implemented [this](https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/blob/a23c0ee78955c76d82bf1b312bbc3d139823d45c/examples/simple_threaded_publisher.py#L20) in one of my Python examples.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded client jar from 3.1.4 to 3.3.5, and found the addBlockedListener API, and yes I got a notification of 'low on disk'.

Comment: However I just wondered why channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10*1000) doesn't work, in my understanding, if no confirmation received after 10 seconds, a timeout exception should be thrown out.